# How to set template in custom block in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I want to set template in **Block** custom.php. how can i do it? 
I tried following:

```
protected function _prepareLayout() {
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Xyaddons\Productzoom\Block\Product\View')->setTemplate('product/image.phtml')->toHtml();

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

it's not running successfully.

**Add new quetion**

I want create funcion in **custom block** use to set template. it same

```
public function setCustomTemplate(){
    if($isActive ==="1"){
       return $this->getLayout()->getBlock('.....')->setTemplate('custom/view.phtml');
      }
}
```

how do it? any thank help :)

Comment: what is the error that you are getting ? the format seems correct. Try removing return from return parent::_prepareLayout(); and check

Comment: it not run file template image.phtml

Comment: I removed it not change.

Comment: You should start your question by stating at a high level what it is you wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

Use  $this->addChild function to add child block. Ex:

```
    $this->addChild(
        'back_button',
        'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button',
        ['label' => __('Back'), 'template' => 'Vendor_Moduel::template.phtml' 'class' => 'cancel']
    );
```

Then in parent block template use `$this->getChildHtml('back_button')`; to render child block with template.

**PS. Better to use layout to define blocks and templates**

Answer (score 4):

In your block file,

```
protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('Magento_Config::page/system/config/robots/reset.phtml');
    }
```

check for `_construct()` method not confused with `__construct()`.

You can set your `Namespace_ModuleName :: path/to/template.phtml`

Comment: I don't need parent consturcter, then How do I declare set template

Comment: you can just remove parent:construct in above function

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, can we pass argument to the template like product id?