# how to create or call block programmatically in magento2

Tags: magento2, blocks, magento-2.0, programmatically

i need to call top menu or header out ide the magento project in that case how to call it in magento2

in magento1.x we use

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/store/app/Mage.php');

$app = Mage::app();
$session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));

$block = $app
    ->getLayout()
    ->getBlockSingleton('checkout/cart_sidebar')
    ->setTemplate('checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml');

echo $block->toHtml();
```

in magento2.0 how to do it?

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88632/how-to-set-template-in-custom-block-in-magento2

Comment: @Manashvibirla:- the link yiu shared will tell how to et template to block or create and child block, but in my case i call the existing block programmatically out ide magento project folder

Comment: what is the object i need to create to create block ?